# set_id is continually looping out IDs

Tags: android, android-fragments, for-loop

I have two fragments. **Fragment A** leads to **Fragment B** - in **fragment B** I am getting data from an external database and saving the values in shared preferences and passing this back to **fragment A**.

In **fragment B**, I have the following, which is handling a JSON array:

```
public ArrayList getAll_question_ids(){
    return all_question_ids;
}

@Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

            ServerResponse resp = response.body();

            //Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)) {

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

                Log.d("Question_IDs", "getAllQuestionID() = " + response.body().getQuestion().getAll_question_ids() );

                editor.putString(Constants.All_QUESTION_IDS,((resp.getQuestion().getAll_question_ids().toString())));
                editor.apply();

                String questionNumber = pref.getString(Constants.All_QUESTION_IDS, "");

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Question ID = " + questionNumber,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                goToCreateQuestionFragment();

            }
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

In **fragment A** I then call a method via the onViewCreated method as shown below:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);

    if ((!pref.getString(Constants.All_QUESTION_IDS, "").equals(null) && !pref.getString(Constants.All_QUESTION_IDS, "").equals(""))) {
        createQuestionButton();
    }
}
```

Inside the **createQuestionButton** method is where I am confused. I have a loop which I am using to assign the values stored in Shared Preferences to a dynamically created button, which is added to a Linear Layout.

I now want to set unique IDs for the buttons and attach an onClickListener so I can create actions for the buttons.

I have read that I can use `View.generateViewId()` for devices using API 17 and above, which is great.

However, when I make a toast to check the value being assigned to each button is being created correctly, I noticed that rather than just assigning one ID, my code keeps executing 4/5 times, so 4/5 ids are being generated per button!

I think this is something to do with the fact that I am calling the method in the onViewCreated but I am not sure how else to call the method.

The method being called is below:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void createQuestionButton() {

    //get all the question_ids from shared pref, that have been stored from the SetQuestion Activity
    //in the allQuestionIDS() method
    String questionNumber = pref.getString(Constants.All_QUESTION_IDS, "");
    //converting the above String back into a List
    questionNumber = questionNumber.substring(1, questionNumber.length() - 1);
    //split the array using the comma
    String[] array = questionNumber.split(", ");
    //Converting questionArray array to a list using Arrays.asList()
    List list = Arrays.asList(array);


    if (!questionNumber.equals("") && !questionNumber.equals(null)) {

        for (Object value : list) {


            try {

        /*Dynamically create new Button which includes the question number
          */

                AppCompatButton btn_question = new AppCompatButton(getActivity());

        /*LayoutParams (int width, int height,float weight)
        As LayoutParams defaults in px, I have called a method called dpToPX to make sure the dynamically added EditText is the same size on all devices.
         */
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(dpToPx(280), dpToPx(45), 1);
                btn_question.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3B5998"));
                btn_question.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                btn_question.setText("Question " + value);
                btn_question.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                //generate unique ID for each new EditText dynamically created
                btn_question.setId(View.generateViewId());
                params.setMargins(0, dpToPx(10), 0, dpToPx(10));
                btn_question.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                btn_question.setLayoutParams(params);
                allEds.add(btn_question);
                mLayout.addView(btn_question);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Question ID = " + btn_question.getId(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to create new button");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance on how this is being caused and best practice to avoid would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have passed a toast in **fragment B** and it appears the results coming across from the server is correct but the toast appears to be hanging on, as if it is toasting the same info multiple times.

I have checked the interpreter and the data coming across is correct so I am not sure why it appears to be stuck in a loop, especially when there is no loop in fragment B!

The JSON being retrieved is as follows:

```
{
  "result": "success",
  "message": "All Questions Have Been Selected",
  "question": {
      "all_question_ids": ["1","2","3"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the debugger to step into your function, and check for the values on `list` variable. A quite likely cause could be the extra space in `questionNumber.split(", ");`. Most probably it should be written like so `questionNumber.split(",");`

Comment: I think you're right and that my loop itself is executing several times and it was just that calling `btn_question.setId(View.generateViewId());` has made this clear. Although, now I need to work out why that is because the data being passed to the loop is correct but the amount of times its looping is incorrect!